# ASP.NET MVC com AngularJs e LayoutPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o melhor dos dois mundos de Asp.net MVC  e AngularJs. Faço as requisições do banco com WEBApi o que funciona muito bem. Mas agora eu adicionei um modulo angular na layout page. O ng-app da layout page funciona perfeitamente, porém agora os módulos das páginas que estão dentro do render body não funcionam. Alguém saberia me dizer o porque o módulo adicionado na layout page atrapalha no funcionamento das outras páginas mesmo em divs não aninhadas. Eu não vou colocar o código aqui porque é uma aplicação comercial e tem muita informação. mas basicamente a estrutura é

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico"/>

    <!--CSS-->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/dashboard")
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div ng-app="LayoutApp">
            <div ng-controller="LayoutCtrl" ng-init="loadInfos()" ng-cloak>

                ... Menus e SideBars

            </div><!--CTRL-->
        </div><!--APP-->

        <div class="content-wrapper">

            <section class="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer class="main-footer">

        </footer>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dashboard")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modulesLayout")

</body>
</html>
```

**e a estrutura das páginas do renderbody**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "T";
    Layout = "~/Areas/MinhaConta/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modulesCtrl")

<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="loadInfos()">



    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-app é pra ser usado duas vezes mesmo?

Comment: então é melhor para cada view eu declarar um controller como é o indicado e todos utilizarem o mesmo ng-app?

Comment: Sim. Só é possível ter um ng-app por página. Vide minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da [documentação do AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

> AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

Tradução

> Aplicações AngularJS não podem ser aninhadas entre si.

Então, não use um `ng-app` dentro de outro `ng-app`.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda!!

Comment: Por nada. Fico feliz em ajudar.

Comment: http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/can-angularjs-have-multiple-ng-app.html Este artigo ajuda a explicar melhor como injetar outros módulos. Acabei de encontrá-lo. Obrigada